# How to concat docx file in python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, database, docx

Below is my code:

```
 v_excel= []
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(paths):
     for t in files:
         if t.endswith('.xlsx'):   
             df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(paths,t), header=None, index_col=False)
             v_excel.append(df)

conc = pd.concat(v_excel, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

conc output:

```
#after appending two excel files i can successively concat the files and put it in 
#seperate column

column1   column2
data1     data1 
data2     data2
data3     data3
data3     data4

#column 1 is from excel file 1 and column2 from excel file 2
```

How to do this for docx as i did for excel ?

```
if t.endswith('.docx'):
    #for c,z in enumerate(t):
        v_doc.append(Document(t))  # <-----how to put this in df and concat according to 
                                   #       docx file as i have done with excel ?
```

docx contains:
#docx contains dummy text's !!!

```
#docx1 contains:
   
data1
data2
data3
data4

#docx2 contains:
   
data5
data6
data7
data8
```

i want to save the content of docx files to columns of excel. docx 1 content to column 1 of excel and docx 2 to column 2 of same excel.

Hope i get some response. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the content of your docx files, which kind of output do you expect? Formatted text and data are different things. As it is, your question is too ambiguous to expect a decent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution #1:** Aggregating multiple .docx documents to single output docx document.

If want to copy the text and style from a collection of docx documents to a single output docx then can use python-docx module.

```python
from docx import Document
import os

master = Document()
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith('.docx'):
        doc = Document(f)
        for p in doc.paragraphs:
            out_para = master.add_paragraph()
            for run in p.runs:                
                output_run = out_para.add_run(run.text)
                # copy style from old to new
                output_run.bold = run.bold
                output_run.italic = run.italic
                output_run.underline = run.underline
                output_run.font.color.rgb = run.font.color.rgb
                output_run.style.name = run.style.name

master.save('out.docx')
```

**Solution #2:** Aggregating table content from multiple .docx documents to single output excel document.

In your comments, you want to create an excel sheet from a set of word documents with tables of text.

Here is Python code to copy cells in tables of Word documents to a target Excel document.

```python
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import os

df = None
for f in os.listdir('data'):
    if f.endswith('.docx'):
        doc = Document(file)
        for table in doc.tables:
            for row in table.rows:
                data = []
                for cell in row.cells:
                    data.append(cell.text)               
                if df is None:
                    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(range(1, len(data)+1)))
                df = df.append(pd.Series(data, index=df.columns),
                               ignore_index=True)

df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

**Solution #3:** Aggregating custom table content from multiple .docx documents to single output excel document with a 2-column table.

In your particular sample data, the table is structured with either 3 or 9 columns so need to concatenate the text of other columns to a single value if want to keep 2 columns in output.

```python
df = None
for f in os.listdir('data'):
    if f.endswith('.docx'):
        doc = Document(file)
        # iterate over all the tables
        for table in doc.tables:
            for row in table.rows:
                cells = row.cells
                if len(cells) > 1:
                    col1 = cells[0].text
                    # check if first column is not empty
                    if col1:
                        # concatenate text of cells to a single value
                        text = ''
                        for i in range(1, len(cells)):
                            if len(text) != 0:
                                text += ' '
                            text += cells[i].text
                        data = [cells[0].text, text]
                        if df is None:
                            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column1', 'column2'])
                        df = df.append(pd.Series(data, index=df.columns),
                                 ignore_index=True)
# save output
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for taking time to help me out. i think i didnt clearly say what i need. i want to save those paragraphs.text of docx in excel in a separate column according to the docx file. docx file 1 to column one of excel likewise docx file 2 to column two of same excel and then final output as excel.

Comment: So one row for each document and each column is for text for each paragraph ? Each word document has the same # of paragraphs ??

Comment: yes exactly i have a table 1 in docx 1 and table 2 in docx 2 i just want to paste those table 1 and table 2 in column 1 and column 2 of excel.

Comment: Might be simpler to share copy of an example word document with same structure rather than create a generic solution.

Comment: here is the link of doc1 and doc2 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PJNeL6jPsfBd-GzHwXKcOKfaHZk8spcr?usp=sharing

Comment: what is process_doc in your code ? NameError: name 'process_doc' is not defined

Comment: i think its file = os.path.join(paths, f)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234726/discussion-between-jasonm1-and-titanium).

Answer (score 1):

You can **docxcompose** to concat docx files in python. you can read more descriptions in [docxcompose's pypi official page](https://pypi.org/project/docxcompose/)